# Escape invalid characters from text field

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a login form that is used to process some database queries in VB. However, when tested on another PC with a username containing symbols such as '@', it falls over with no error.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Login.Click
    Dim passStr As String = Password.Text
    Dim userStr As String = Username.Text
    ...
```

I think it is due to invalid characters ruining the query, but am not sure how I can accept the login details, escaping them all.

I have found a way of removing them from the string but that is not very helpful when I need the login details to be valid!

Comment: You should parameterize your database queries. That way you do not need to worry about what characters are used (as long as you are not constructing dynamic SQL queries in the database).

Comment: Could you add the actual code that fails? As is this question is off-topic because questions asking _why my code is not working_ require a reproducible example of that code.

Answer (score 0):

Any way it is better to save password in an encrypted format. i will suggest you an encryption mechanism to store the password in an encrypted format. following is the function:

```
Imports System.Text.UnicodeEncoding
Dim uni As New UnicodeEncoding()
Public Function encodeUTF(ByVal inputString As String) As String '<-- function for encoding the input string
    Dim byt() As Byte = uni.GetBytes(inputString)
    encodeUTF = ""
    For Each b As Byte In byt
        encodeUTF &= b & ","
    Next
    Trim(Replace(encodeUTF, ",", ""))
End Function
```

hence your coding becomes:

```
Dim passStr As String = encodeUTF(Password.Text)
Dim userStr As String = encodeUTF(Username.Text)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting an unhandled exception now: "Argument 'Prompt' cannot be converted to type 'String'. Any ideas?

Comment: That is barely encryption. Substitution ciphers are easy to crack. For the best security, hashes of passwords should be stored, not passwords or encrypted passwords: [Salted Password Hashing - Doing it Right](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm).